# Test char at point

Tags: characters

I want to test if char at point is, let's say, "{"

I found:

```
(string= "{" (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (+ 1 (point))))
```

and:

```
(string-match-p "{" (what-cursor-position))
```

both working.

In the sencond case, if there isn't something better, I'd like to hide the message in the echo area (minibuffer).

Some hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `char-after` like so:

```
(eq ?{ (char-after))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I think it's usually preferable to use `=` for character comparison, seeing as the `eq`uality of Elisp integers is mostly an implementation detail.

Comment: @Basil, I'm pretty sure it's an implementation detail which is never ever going to change, so I don't feel it's a problem, but `=` is certainly fine as well.

Comment: Oh, absolutely; my comment was for good style/dwim moreso than warning.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook `char-after` for the simpler `following-char`. The former can return `nil`, in which case `eq` is needed and `=` would eventually fail, whereas the latter is guaranteed to return an integer, and so in newer Emacs sources you would usually see `(= (following-char) ?{)`.

Comment: `char-before` did what I wanted.