# Any way to embed links with part of their content in Emacs?

Tags: hyperlinks

The question itself might be confusing given I'm using the word `embed` here, which have different meaning. What i mean by that is:

- Embed like what chat.stackoverflow does. Say I'm posting a single SO/SE link (from a post) on any chat on SO/SE, it will embed like so:

[image: embedded test]

Where [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38698/test-char-at-point) is the embedded link (do bear in mind this is just an example to illustrate what i mean, and not intended to be the final form).

Basically, what i mean by embed is either:

- Show a part of the link, either at the start, end or any wanted part?
- Show the whole content of the link in current buffer, but in a separate block (so it doesn't clutter any other existing text in the current buffer)

I'm also aware of possibly related things, like [org-screenshot](https://github.com/dfeich/org-screenshot), though it's not exactly what i want, but still useful.

How could i do this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: yes, but I'm indirectly asking this *to be made in elisp*. Though it is true I wasn't sure of which tags would be right for this post - Any recommendation is welcome :) @Drew

Comment: nevermind, just saw you edited the tag. Disregard what i said in my last comment :D @Drew

Comment: Org mode [Hyperlinks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Hyperlinks.html#Hyperlinks)? Is that close to what you are looking for?

Comment: Sadly no, as it doesn't *embed* them like in the example i provided in my post (afaik) @NickD

Comment: You might want to check my Emacs extension org-link-beautify (https://github.com/stardiviner/org-link-beautify) It provides video preview. The implementation is here https://github.com/stardiviner/org-link-beautify/blob/master/org-link-beautify.el#L152   I think you can use similar way to embed URL content.  (P.S If you want to implement this feature, PR welcome)

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew that one :D I'll check it out and try to contribute @stardiviner

Comment: I learnt the feature via Discourse's [Onebox](https://github.com/discourse/onebox) which "turning media URLs into simple HTML previews of the resource", it requires the target websites supports some protocols such as facebook opengraph and twitter card, these info is easy to get since they are part of the HTML meta headers, StackExchange supports both. Not sure what you want, Emacs is a plain text environment it's char-by-char not pixel by pixel unlike the web browser.

Comment: basically like what inline image embed in Emacs does (where it temporary preview it) but for links (like what SO/SE does, but not necessarily exactly the same, see what stardiviner said in his comment which look similar to what i want) @xuchunyang

Comment: onebox is a good idea too, though it depend on the HTML meta headers, but that's probably fine as an alternative :) @xuchunyang feel free to post this as answer too